# Binding only part of a label

Tags: wpf, binding, label

How would one achieve mixing bound values with constant text in a WPF bound control?

For example, say I have a form displaying orders, and I want a label that displays text like "Order ID 1234".

I've tried things like:

```
text="Order ID {Binding ....}"
```

Is this achievable, or do I have to do something like having more than one label in a flow control?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you're using 3.5 SP1, you can use the `StringFormat` property on the binding:

```
<Label Content="{Binding Order.ID, StringFormat=Order ID \{0\}}"/>
```

Otherwise, use a converter:

```
<local:StringFormatConverter x:Key="StringFormatter" StringFormat="Order ID {0}" />
<Label Content="{Binding Order.ID, Converter=StringFormatter}"/>
```

With `StringFormatConverter` being an `IValueConverter`:

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(object), typeof(string))]
public class StringFormatConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public string StringFormat { get; set; }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType,
                          object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
         if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(StringFormat)) return "";
         return string.Format(StringFormat, value);
    }


    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType,
                              object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
```

That'll do the trick.

[**Edit** : Change the `Text` property to `Content`]

Comment: With the stringformat example, what happens if the string needs to contain a comma?  Do you then have no choice but to go with the converter option?

Comment: AFAIK the label control does not have the `Text` property. You should bind to the `Content` property

Answer (score 53):

The Binding.StringFormat property doesn't work on Labels, you need to use the ContentStringFormat property on the Label.
For example, the following sample will work:

```
<Label>
    <Label.Content>
        <Binding Path="QuestionnaireName"/>
    </Label.Content>
    <Label.ContentStringFormat>
        Thank you for taking the {0} questionnaire
    </Label.ContentStringFormat>
</Label>
```

The same as short Version:

```
<Label Content="{Binding QuestionnaireName}" ContentStringFormat="Thank you for taking the {0} questionnaire" />
```

Using it to display a unit after the value:

```
<Label Content="{Binding Temperature}" ContentStringFormat="{}{0}°C" />
```

While this sample will not:

```
<Label>
    <Label.Content>
        <Binding Path="QuestionnaireName" StringFormat="Thank you for taking the {0} questionnaire"/>
    </Label.Content>            
</Label>
```

Comment: Sigh. Another arbitrary restriction imposed by WPF developers.

Comment: Since `Label.Content` is of type `Object`, the binding sees no need to convert and format the value as a string.

Comment: This one is really the answer to the question.

Answer (score 5):

Often overlooked is simply chaining multiple textblocks together for example

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstName}" />
<TextBlock Text=" " />
<TextBlock Text="{Binding LastName}" />
```

Comment: This will be displayed on 3 separate lines.

Comment: this depends on what kind of stackpanel it's in

Answer (score 4):

Another approach is to use a single TextBlock with multiple Run elements within it:

```
<TextBlock><Run>Hello</Run><Run>World</Run></TextBlock>
```

.. but to bind to a  element you need to use add a [BindableRun](http://fortes.com/2007/03/bindablerun/) class.

**Update** But there are some drawbacks to this technique ... see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd569761.aspx)

Comment: This one is the choice if you want also a different formatting (number in bold f.e.)

Answer (score 3):

I found another one approach. @Inferis's solution doesn't work for me and @LPCRoy's isn't elegant for me:

```
<Label Content="{Binding Path=Order.ID, FallbackValue=Placeholder}" ContentStringFormat="Order ID {0}">
```

It's my favourite at this moment, it's seems flexible and condensed.

Answer (score 0):

Modified Mikolaj's answer.

```
<Label Content="{Binding Order.ID}" ContentStringFormat="Order ID {0}" />
```

FallbackValue is not a must.