# Why is binding result different on a Label and a TextBox?

Tags: wpf, binding

I was using the following XAML:

```
<Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Content="Datum"/>
<Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Content="{Binding TimeStamp, StringFormat={}{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff}}"/>
<Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Content="Level"/>
<Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" Content="{Binding Level}"/>
```

but the TimeStamp was being formatted like this:

```
2.24.2012 7:38
```

I started up [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) (great tool!) and noticed that the Label is actually composed of a TextBox and that this TextBox contained the TimeStamp formatted as I defined it. I then replaced the Label with a TextBox and I get the TimeStamp correctly formatted.

```
<TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding TimeStamp, StringFormat={}{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff}}"/>

2012-02-24 07:38:23.123
```

I have defined no Resource, Trigger or Style blocks to override Label behaviour so I'm wondering why this is happening.

Any ideas?

Comment: Even binding to a DateTime without a StringFormat produces different results (depends on culture settings I guess).  On my system by default TextBlock shows seconds, Label doesn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Binding.StringFormat property doesn't work on Labels, you need to use the ContentStringFormat property on the Label

```
<Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Content="{Binding TimeStamp}">
    <Label.ContentStringFormat>0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff</Label.ContentStringFormat>
</Label>
```

also see [Binding only part of a label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/667511/wpf-binding-only-part-of-a-label)

Comment: Ok - that's a surprise but here's an interesting comment '*Since Label.Content is of type Object, the binding sees no need to convert and format the value as a string*' so I guess it makes some kind of sense. I have to assume that String Formatting is not applied to **any** Content tag. right?