# wpf set property to static resource with string manipulation

Tags: wpf, xaml, resources, label

I'm creating a WPF application. It has two labels which use the same static string resource, but with some differences. For example, it has a string resource with the key `string1` and value `SuccessRate`. I want the first label to be `SuccessRate` and the second `Label` to be `SuccessRate(%)`. I define the first label with:

```
<Label Content="{StaticResource string1}" />
```

How can I define the second `Label`?

Comment: Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/667511/binding-only-part-of-a-label)

Answer (score 0):

You might set the `Content` of the second Label to a [`TextBlock`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms617591.aspx) with two [`Run`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms522796.aspx) elements:

```
<Label>
    <TextBlock>
        <Run Text="{StaticResource string1}"/>
        <Run Text="(%)"/>
    </TextBlock>
</Label>
```

---

Perhaps you need to have only TextBlocks instead of Labels anyway:

```
<TextBlock Text="{StaticResource string1}"/>
<TextBlock>
    <Run Text="{StaticResource string1}"/>
    <Run Text="(%)"/>
</TextBlock>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ContentStringFormat`

```
<Label Content="{StaticResource string1}" ContentStringFormat="{}{0}(%)" ... />
```

Note that format starts with `{}`. It's just something what has to be there if your format starts with. `{`

You can read about `ContentStringFormat` on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.contentstringformat.aspx).